# in plot of R, korean words are broken

Tags: r, encoding, plot

I test the wordcloud.
I set the encoding as UTF-8 in tool menu, RStudio and read txt file as UTF-8 with read("filename",encoding="UTF-8").
But korean words are broken in window of plot and I can't read.

What shoud I do for reading korean words.

Answer (score 1):

I got it as setting below...

> par(family="AppleGothic")